# CASE WHEN in WHERE clause is failing with an error missing keyword

Tags: oracle, plsql

In oracle, I am trying to use date as a condition in where clause. What I am looking for is to get employees with if they were created after 7th May 2020, dont use the condition XML_VAL NOT LIKE '%%' but if they were created before then, no extra condition. I am trying to implement like below, but its throwing missing keyword near not like in the case statement. I am not sure what it is I am missing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOGINID
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE EmployeeCode NOT IN ('L35', 'L36') and
    CASE WHEN (CREATE_DT < '07-MAY-20') THEN XML_VAL NOT LIKE '%<Product>%' END
```

Comment: `'07-MAY-20'` is not a `DATE` data type; it is a string literal and you are relying on an implicit conversion from a string to a `DATE`. Do **NOT** do that; use a date literal such as `DATE '2020-05-07'` or the function `TO_DATE( '07-MAY-20', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American' )`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a `CASE` expression like that as the `THEN` clause expects a single expression and not a comparison. Instead you want:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       LOGINID
FROM   EMPLOYEES
WHERE  EmployeeCode NOT IN ('L35', 'L36')
AND    (  CREATE_DT >= DATE '2020-05-07'
       OR XML_VAL NOT LIKE '%<Product>%' )
```

---

> I am not sure what it is I am missing.

If you really want to use a `CASE` expression then this would be syntactically valid:

```sql
CASE
WHEN CREATE_DT < TO_DATE('07-MAY-20', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American')
THEN XML_VAL
ELSE NULL
END NOT LIKE '%<Product>%'
```